# cannot get Mac to do dns-sd to CUPS print queue

Tags: macos, dns, printing, network-printer

I'm trying to create DNS records so that Macs on our network can auto-detect available printers via dns-sd (broadcast alone isn't an option due to our WAN environment)

If I manually "Add" the CUPS IPP queue via "IP->cups.server.name->/printers/queueName" it all works just fine, but if I add the appropriate PTR/SRV DNS records, it doesn't

A sniffer shows the Mac doing the _dns-sd._udp.XXXX lookups, finds the cups server, does the TXT lookup to get the queue details all just fine. But when I print to this new queue, the sniffer shows it connects to the cups IPP server as "POST / HTTP" instead of "POST /printers/queueName" - and of course cups responds with "The printer or class was not found". The print job then ends up paused on the Mac

"rp=printers/queueName" (without leading "/") is definitely in the TXT record, but it looks like the Mac is simply ignoring it???

;; ANSWER SECTION:
queueName._ipp._tcp.our.domain. 1800 IN TXT "\"txtvers=1\" \"qtotl=1\" \"URF=none\" \"product=(Generic PostScript Printer)\" \"ty=Generic PostScript Printer\" \"note=Jason Test\" \"transparent=t\" \"copies=t\" \"duplex=t\" \"color=t\" \"pdl=application/postscript\" \"rp=printers/queueName\""

Any ideas what I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question

The problem was that we use Microsoft DNS and you've got to be careful when making dns-sd TXT records. They are typically reported in the following format

1800 IN TXT "txtvers=1" "qtotl=1" "URF=none" "product=(Generic PostScript Printer)" "ty=Generic PostScript Printer" "note=Jason Test" "transparent=t " "copies=t " "duplex=t " "color=t " "pdl=application/postscript " "rp=printers/queueName"

...but if you look at my question above, you'll see they were full of "\"" chars - which screwed up the Mac (actually probably any client)

The trick is when using the Microsoft DNS GUI, to enter these multi-phrase TXT records with no quotes and hit enter between the bits. ie

```
    txtvers=1
    qtotl=1
    product=(Generic PostScript Printer)
    URF=none
```

Once I changed our records, the Macs happily gobbled up the metadata, didn't even prompt me for a print driver and successfully printed. :-)